# Writing characters under lim

Tags: positioning, math-operators

I want to write

```
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$
```

whereby `n \to \infty` should be written directly under `\lim`.

How can this be done?

Comment: the subscript would go underneath in display math, you would not normally want it underneath in _inline_ math as it has to fit in a normal baseline (compare changing `$...$` to `\[..\]`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would do

```
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$
```

Which gives

[image]

but, as David Carlisle said, that might not be what you want to do.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with David, but it *can* be done, like this:

```
$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} i\bar z$
```

Comment: you left out something very important ...

Comment: Haha, indeed!!!

Comment: @heather beat me by 23 seconds anyway....

Comment: @JPi, sorry about that, though I did do a double take when I first read your answer before the edit (I even copy-pasted it into sharelatex to make sure I wasn't missing something). =)